# Azure relay hybrid connection listener not reestablishing when internet is disrupted

Tags: azure-relay

I have **CUSTOM** azure hybrid connection listener service running on premise with below mention code as MSDN suggested, but listener not getting reestablished when **on premise INTERNET** connectivity get disrupted.

Only 1 out of 10 times, listener getting reestablished with below code, when **on premise INTERNET** is disrupted

```
// Opening the listener establishes the control channel to  
// the Azure Relay service. The control channel is continuously   
// maintained, and is reestablished when connectivity is disrupted       
  await listener.OpenAsync(cts.Token);

//Below delegate not getting called when INTERNET plugged off from 
//listener running machine
  listener.Offline += listener_Offline;
```

What changes required to reestablish listener to azure hybrid connection 10 out of 10 times?. Please advice.

Comment: (While I think the correct word use to be *on premises* (and *please advise*, at that), I'd avoid the issue using *LAN connectivity* (where appropriate).)

Comment: We are not here to do spell bee. Moreover above is not solution not even workaround. Certainly not the answer looking for from stack overflow.Disgrace.